# Maximo view wildcard attributs

Tags: view, maximo

I want to make a view with attributs that have wildcard search type. Originally attributs have wildcard as a serach type. But they change to none after view is created. I cant change them after database is created, because they are read-only. Is there a way to set search type with SQL or is there a diffrent solution to this problem.

My SQL code:

```
CREATE VIEW testviewv AS 
SELECT workorder.WORKTYPE, workorder.STATUS, person.DISPLAYNAME 
FROM workorder, person 
where workorder.OWNER = person.PERSONID
```

Comment: Please confirm you are running that SQL code (DDL, really) and then going to Database Configuration in Maximo and clicking New and putting `testviewv` for the object name, causing the Imported? check box to get a check in it. I'm just trying to check the order of operations in case that matters.

Comment: Yes i did the import and updated the database so i can make an Enterprise Service. What check box do i need to check i didnt check anything other then default boxes?